# Unable to view the console exe. window screen

Tags: c#, .net, exe

Unable to view the console application (developed in C#) black window screen,  triggered from my Asp.net core web application hosted in IIS.

I can see my batch running in Task Manager, But the window doesn't appear.

This is my code:

```
try 
{
       Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Upload_batch");
       if (pname.Length > 0)
       {
            TempData["successMessage"] = "Batch already in Process";
       }
       else
       {
            logErr.entityLogErrorFile("if process", _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\xx\\xx\\Upload_batch.exe";

            myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            myProcess.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(myProcess);

            TempData["successMessage"] = "Batch Process triggered Successfully";

        }
        return RedirectToAction("create", "CreateTemplate");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     logErr.entityLogErrorFile(ex.Message, _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

     return RedirectToAction("Login", "login");
}
```

Comment: Your IIS is likely running under a different account. Just like I can't see your console windows, even if you and I are both logged into the same PC, you can't see windows launched by the IIS user.

Comment: No other way to view the console window?

Comment: Where do you expect that window to show up? This is server-side code and can only show up on the server, not the client. And even then that server process may not have access to any desktop

Comment: yes i want to view it on the server side, Need to view the console window in server Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can help you with that [DEBUG -> ATTACH TO PROCESS] or [CTRL + ALT + P].
Make sure in opened window "Show processes for all users is on", search by the name you gave to the process.

[image]

You can do a live debug on your console app, I believe that is what you are looking for.

Check this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: But is it possible to debug the console application  to my local (which was running in different server)  with the help of server credentials.

Comment: I don't think so, if it was web app under (IIS) you could do it, but still it might be possible, I never did it, I'll give it a try :).

Comment: Might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications

Comment: and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-installed-app-package?view=vs-2017